# Send intent to sms app android 4.4 and above

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using this code to send intent default sms app in my application

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", number);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",message);

        if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            context.startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
```

This code open an sms app in android 5 (and probably in kitkat!) but it may or may not be the default sms app! So sometimes when it does not open default sms app i get an error because only default app can send sms!

my question is how to insure only default app handles my intents ?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this-

```
smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

this should ensure the recipient app is the default one.

Or alternatively for KK, you could try this-

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("Phone Number", null, "Message", null, null);
```

N.B: Using this method requires that your app has the SEND_SMS permission.

For further information, please see [sendTextMessage() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: I tested first option in android 5. It has no effects. apps still tries to send it with non default app